# How to get the bounds of a panel set by Miglayout manager before it is displayed?

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

There are three different kinds of panel each spanning different number of grids. 1*3 , 1*1 , 3*1 .

```
add(panel1, "span 1 3,push, grow");
add(panel2, "push, grow");
add(panel3, "span 3 1,push, grow");
```

I want to change first panel's constraint to "span 1 2" when it overlaps with other panel on the screen. But to find out whether it overlaps with another panel I have to know it's bounds.

I did not set any size constraints.

Is there any way , to know 'the bounds before the panel/component is actually displayed'?

And also, how to know the length of the rows and columns set by the MigLayout manager?

Actually I want to cover  the full screen with these differently sized panels.

EDIT :

I forgot to enter the main culprit ...`add(lastPanel, span, push, grow)`

I am trying to cover the full screen with differently sized panels. This code works for even number of rectangles but not for odd. When they are odd in number, then the last grid is always left empty . So I spanned the last panel to cover the full empty available space, but then it overlapped with the 3*1 panel.

Comment: don't understand what you mean by "overlap" - what exactly do you want to achieve? Those many push constraints are a tad unusual... Conditional layout is not supported, afaik (and not needed, most of the time) Please show an example, preferably in code, at least a sketch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this similar problem again but this time I got the answer, I might be helpful for someone, so I am posting it here.

```
addAncestorListener(new AncestorListener() {
        @Override
        public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent event) {
                height = getHeight();
                width = getWidth();
                //Modifications to the components here.
        }
```

I wanted the dimensions set by the LayoutManager at compile time (which was not possibe). The AncestorListener did  the trick, as soon as the components were laid out on the screen . It captures the dimensions and modified the components accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple of ways, not really nice or pretty and all suffer from the same issue.

Layouts can occur repetitively in succession (that is you will be clobbered with a number of request to layout the container in quick succession)

The trap is trying to figure out when it's come to stop.  The next problem is known when you've caused it.

You "could" override the parent `Container`s `doLayout` method, after you've called `super.doLayout` you will have access to the resulting layout.  This is not the best solution as it requires you to implement the `Container` which you may not want to to.

The other solution I can think of  is using a `ComponentListener` on `panel1` on monitor the `componentResized` event.

I would **seriously** play around with these and see what trouble you're getting yourself into.  A better solution is to try and work out your layout issues ahead of time.

Comment: I just simply forced the user to enter even number of rectangles or added myself one if the user enters odd number of rectangles. Sorry for the less info before. Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

`JPanel` (by default valid for every `Swing JComponents`) returns its `Size` or `Bounds` in two cases

1. if is once time visible on the screen
2. after `pack()` to the `Top-Level Container`

there no reason to know any of this value for `Standard LayoutManagers`, nor for MigLayout,

Comment: Hmm... yes but I was just wondering if there is any way or hack exist to know beforehand what my layout manager would going to do. Anyway thanks for your time.